# Pointer to gpu memory to Python from CUDA C

Tags: python, cuda, ctypes

I use python and CUDA C. I am trying to pass from one function to another, a pointer to data in
GPU memory.
But but I only get 32 bits of address, out of 64.

Python code:

```
HostToDevice = Synth_dll.HostToDevice
HostToDevice.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_size_t]
HostToDevice.restypes = c_void_p


DeviceToHost = Synth_dll.DeviceToHost
DeviceToHost.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p, c_size_t]


host = np.array([ [1, 20, 30, 40]]).astype(np.float32)
host_copy = np.array([ [0, 0, 0, 0]]).astype(np.float32)

host_c = c_void_p(host.ctypes.data)
host_copy_c = c_void_p(host_copy.ctypes.data)


dev_c = HostToDevice(host_c, len)
DeviceToHost(host_copy_c, dev_c, len)
```

C code:

```
 extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) float * HostToDevice(float * host,  size_t N)
 {
  int size = N * sizeof(float);
  int err;
  float *device;
  cudaMalloc((void**)&device, size);
  err = cudaMemcpy(device, host, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  printf("Host To Device error: %d\n", err);
  printf("mem addres: %p\n", device);
  return device;
  }

  extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void DeviceToHost(float *host, void *device, size_t N)
 {
  int  err;
  int size = N*sizeof(float);

  err = cudaMemcpy(host, device, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
//  for (int i=0; i < N; i+=1) { printf("%f\n",host[i]); }
  printf("Device To Host error %d\n", err);
  printf("mem addres %p\n", device);
 }
```

Output:

```
Host To Device error: 0
mem addres: 0000000B22A40600
Device To Host error 1
mem addres 0000000022A40600
```

Comment: maybe your python installation is a 32-bit python.

Comment: import platform
  ...: platform.architecture()
Out[6]: ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')